# Display Array List From Left To Right

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to display an array list from left to right with a div scroll. But it become top to bottom. How should I do to solve it? This my [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/to-display-the-array-data-as-a-list-xjsgvz) as you reference.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h2 class="ylet-primary-500 alignleft">Sessions</h2>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div *ngFor="let batch of batches">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h3 class="classes">
        {{batch.month}}
        <span class="chips"> </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
      <p class="timings">
        <mat-icon matPrefix>access_time</mat-icon><span>{{batch.time}}</span>
        <span class="slots"> <mat-icon>list_alt</mat-icon>{{batch.slots}}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 70%;
  direction: rtl;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap loop div container with div container and add css flex style.

```
<div class="container">
<div *ngFor="let batch of batches">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h3 class="classes">
        {{batch.month}}
        <span class="chips"> </span>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;">
      <p class="timings">
        <mat-icon matPrefix>access_time</mat-icon><span>{{batch.time}}</span>
        <span class="slots"> <mat-icon>list_alt</mat-icon>{{batch.slots}}</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: It should work. Might something wrong. You could check online website is working in above screenshot. )

Comment: You can add one more css property flex-wrap: wrap for overflow. http://prntscr.com/r4wij5

Comment: thanks so much brother it work... The problem come from other class css